# Qual a diferença entre "o Google" e "a Google"?

Tags: português-europeu, concordância-nominal

Existe alguma diferença entre dizer "o Google" ou "a Google"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*<sup>**Nota:** Eu falo pt-PT: Português (Portugal)</sup>*

Eu uso ambos, mas em situações diferentes:

- O google – o motor de busca.
- A Google – a empresa.

---

**EDIT:** A [resposta de Otavio Macedo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/527/201) fez me pensar que talvez no Brasil essa distinção não seja feita (ou tão utilizada) como em Portugal.

Por exemplo, na página de apresentação da própria empresa Google, o artigo utilizado varia conforme a variante da língua selecionada:

- > **[Acerca da Google](https://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-PT/about/)** — *pt-PT: **Português (Portugal)***
  >
  > A missão **da Google** é organizar a informação do mundo e torná-la
  >   universalmente acessível e útil.
  >
  > *Carreiras **na Google**:* Já imaginou como será a vida
  >   **na Google** ou que vantagens pode ter enquanto funcionário **da
  >   Google**? Procure um emprego **na Google** ou consulte uma das
  >   nossas localizações em todo o mundo.
- > **[Sobre o Google](https://www.google.pt/intl/pt-BR/about/)** — *pt-BR: **Português (Brasil)***
  >
  > A missão **do Google** é organizar as informações do mundo e
  >   torná-las mundialmente acessíveis e úteis.
  >
  > *Carreiras **no Google**:* Você já se perguntou como é a vida
  >   **no Google** ou que benefícios esperar como *um Googler*? Procure
  >   uma vaga  **no Google** ou confira um de nossos escritórios em
  >   todo o mundo.

Comment: Eu acredito que seja apenas mesmo essa a diferença.  
Eu também pessoalmente uso as duas versões dentro desse mesmo contexto.

Comment: Em geral eu faço esse mesmo uso, especialmente quando preciso deixar clara a diferença.

Comment: *EDIT 1 was posted/publicado.*

Answer (score 4):

Nos textos publicados pela própria empresa, no seu site, eles usam o artigo masculino tanto para se referir ao [mecanismo de busca](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/463?hl=pt-BR) ("acesse o Google", "tornando o Google sua página inicial") quanto à própria [empresa](https://www.google.com.br/intl/pt-BR/about/) ("Sobre o Google", "Carreiras no Google"). O artigo masculino também é usado para os demais produtos ("o YouTube", "o Picasa" etc).

Comment: Depende da variante do Português: [http://google.pt/intl/pt-PT/about](http://google.pt/intl/pt-PT/about). Vê a [minha resposta atualizada](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/488/201).

Comment: Sim, sim, quanto *ao YouTube*, *ao Picasa*, e *ao Gmail*, estes *produtos* também são tratados no masculino aqui em Portugal. Mas eu acho que isso tem mais que ver com o género que se torna normal usar com a palavra, e não simplesmente ao "tipo" de coisa (empresa, produto, etc).