# Género dos nomes próprios de empresas

Tags: gênero

Em português é preciso usar o artigo antes os nomes próprios (**o** João, **a** Susana etc). No caso de empresas, é frequentemente feminino (**a** Microsoft, **a** Apple), mas eu também vi o masculino usado (**o** Google, **o** Facebook).

A minha pergunta: há regras / heurísticas por isso ou é completamente aleatório é preciso aprender as formas diferentes?

Ou seria que "o Facebook" venha de "*o **site** / **sítio** Facebook*"?

Comment: Relacionado: http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/487/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-o-google-e-a-google

Comment: Na verdade, não é sempre preciso usar artigo antes de nome de pessoa. É comum omiti-lo na escrita e, em regiões do Brasil, mesmo na fala. E qualifiquei o 'não é preciso' com o 'sempre' só porque, pelo menos em Portugal, na fala nome nome de pessoa sem artigo soaria estranho e emproado.

Comment: Depende! Às vezes é complicado, assim como nomes de cidade. Mas em geral você está certo tipo: A (empresa) Wolkswagen frabrica o (carro) Wolkswagen. Google já vi em ambos os gêneros, algo tipo: A (empresa) Google mantém o (buscador/site) Google. Na dúvida  use A empresa acme que dai você não corre o risco de errar

Answer (score 7):

**Uma rápida observação nos permite concluir que usa-se muito mais o artigo definido feminino quando nos referimos a empresas e marcas.**

> - a Microsoft, a Apple, a Pfizer, a Medtronic, a Sony, a C.I.A., a Universal Films, a Longmans, a Lindt, a Nestlé, a Volkswagen, a Ford, a Honda, a Citroën, a Nike, a Adidas, a Motorola, a Samsung, a Longman, a Oxford University Press, a La Roche-Posay, a Nivea, a Shell, a Toyota, a Hyundai, a Chevron, a General Motors, a General Electric, a Hewlett-Packard, a IBM, a Mitsubishi, a Boeing, a Peugeot, a American Airlines, a Air Portugal, a Lufthansa, a/o Google(sim, uma parcela significativa da população diz "a Google" aqui no Brasil)

**Poucos exemplos pude encontrar com o uso do artigo definido masculino.**

> - o (site) Google, Facebook, Hotmail, IMDB, o (super-mercado) Walmart, Carrefour, o (banco) Citybank, Bank of America, Santander.

Minha conclusão é que, **a princípio, usa-se o artigo no feminino** provavelmente como se estivessemos nos referindo "à empresa tal", "à marca tal", etc. As **exceções seriam os "bancos", os "sites" e os "super-mercados"**.

Contudo, em alguns casos podemos usar tanto o artigo masculino quanto o feminino, mas com uma diferença semântica.

> - "a Boeing fabricou 280 aeronaves em 2014" (empresa) x  "o Boeing 747" (o avião)
> - "as ações da Honda..." (empresa) x "o Honda Civic" (o carro)
> - "a Lindt vai lançar um novo tipo..." (empresa) x "o Lindt que comprei" (o chocolate)
> - "a Volkswagen fez um recall de..." (empresa) x "o Volkswagen que está estacionado/aparcado aqui em frente" (o carro)

Answer (score 5):

A regra geral é a de que se usa o feminino porque se subentende a palavra "empresa"/"companhia"/"sociedade"/"associação": *a (empresa) Microsoft*.

Mas há de facto exceções. Para algumas classes de empresas, subentendem-se outros termos como "banco":

> (1) **O [banco] Barclays** escolheu o antigo banqueiro **do [banco] JPMorgan**, Jes Staley, para CEO.

No caso do J.P. Morgan, também se pode contudo usar o feminino. Porquê não sei.

Outro tipo de empresas com que subentende outra palavra são "fundo de investimento" e "supermercado":

> (2) **O [fundo] Mill Residential Reit**, o primeiro fundo de investimento britânico que comprava casas para depois as colocar no mercado de arrendamento (conhecido como “buy-to-let”), encerrou menos de um ano depois de entrar na bolsa.
>   (3) **O [supermercado] Lidl Portugal** é mais uma vez a cadeia de distribuição que mais Maçã de Alcobaça embalada comprou e vendeu no decorrer da campanha de comercialização 2014/2015.

No entanto, se o fundo ou o supermercado for distinto da empresa que o detém, usar-se-á na mesma o feminino para a empresa.

O caso dos *sites* é mais ambíguo. Pode dizer-se "o/a Google" ou "o/a Yahoo" para referir a empresa (mas apenas "o" para referir o *site*). O masculino usar-se-á tanto mais quanto, na mente do falante, o *site* se confunde com a empresa.

A outra exceção ocorre quando o nome da empresa é um nome comum, mesmo que seja uma sigla ou até uma palavra inglesa (mas nesse caso menos marcado):

> (4) **Os CTT [Correios, Telégrafos e Telefones]** foram privatizados em 2013.

Penso que é esta a principal razão por que "a Facebook" é muito incomum. "Book" significa "livro" em português, que é um nome masculino.

Este fenómeno ocorre com outros tipos de nomes:

> (5) Compra isso antes **na Amazon**.

Repara que (5) se refere ao *site*, não à empresa e que mesmo assim se usa "a" ("Amazónia" é feminino).

Comment: Good.  +1......  Também falamos na Amazon aqui no Brasil.  Acho que é porque lembra "a Amazônia".    Não entendi bem o nome do supermercado.  Lidl ?  Como se pronuncia isso ?

Comment: `"Book" significa "livro" em português, que é masculina.` - *masculino

Comment: @ANeves A minha ideia era "que é (uma palavra) masculina". Mas alterei para ficar mais claro.

Comment: @Centaurus É uma cadeia alemã. Pronuncia-se como se escreve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=123vjAf2wqw

Answer (score 0):

Vai depender do motivo do interlocutor.
Ele pode optar por querer usar o sujeito oculto antes da marca, como por exemplo:

- A (empresa) Google
- O (site) Google
  Ou evitar ambiguidade. Para exemplificar, digamos que exista um estúdio de música chamado Disco, vejam porquê nesse caso o correto seria usar o "a":
- O disco. / Vou lá no disco. / Conhece o disco?
- A Disco. / Vou lá na Disco. / Conhece a Disco?
  Evitando confusão no entendimento dos interlocutores.